# Can't add image in Phaser 2.3.0

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, phaser-framework

I'm trying to add an image to my canvas but I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasLoaded' of undefined
```

It says the error is coming from this line:

```
this.add.image('block',100,255);
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Camera Learning</title>
        <script src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/states/boot.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            (function(){
                var game = new Phaser.Game(450, 510, Phaser.AUTO, 'game');
                game.state.add('boot', boot);
                game.state.start('boot');
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

boot.js:

```
boot = function(game){
    console.log("%cStarting my awesome game", "color:white; background:red");
};

boot.prototype = {

    preload: function(){
        this.load.image('block','./res/borderblock.png');
    },

    create: function(){
        console.log('adding');
        this.add.image('block',100,255);
        console.log('added');       
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.add.image('block',100,255);` should be `this.add.image(100, 255, 'block');` - arguments order does matter and when the method receives a string instead of a number, things naturally don't work. In this case you have x, y and the image's key.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

To add image `this.add.image(x,y,'key');` or you can use 'sprite' like `this.add.sprite(x,y,'key');`